# Redesigning a Raspberry Pi 0 W

Tags: pi-zero

I want to redesign the Raspberry Pi 0 W to fit it into a USB stick. I wonder if there are manufacturing documents - particularly the wiring layers to allow for the controlled modification that will allow redesign it with a smaller form factor with minimal effort. I plan also to remove components that relate to video and audio processing.

Comment: I wonder about the NEGATIVISM. Why voted down?

Comment: maybe because you did not ask a question

Comment: You haven't done any research before asking the question.

Comment: @jsotola the English language is quite clear about the use of the word "wonder"

Comment: @ben_nuttall It is quite a Chutzpa to say I did not done research - if interested I can send you at least 20 URLs I visited in attempt to uncover such documentation. The respectful response I received explains that it seems that I will not find such hacking! For the Beaglebone (not included in these URLs) there are quite detailed information allowing for FULL production, and thus supporting redesign.

Comment: @ben_nuttall and jsotola What is "faulty" in the design of the Raspberry Pi 0 W (and I believe for the rest of the Raspberry based products) Is that only one fully supported USB connection is available (the other one is for power only!), thus limiting applications as the one I am attempting - connecting a peripheral via the Pi0W to a PC/notebook. As result I need to redesign of the Pi0W to replace the POWER only USB with a FULL USB connection. So here is the story - can you now help?

Comment: BeagleBone is OSHW, Raspberry Pi is not. Therefore you cannot achieve what you are asking. There is no more to be said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It's not open source hardware. Members of the public cannot produce Raspberry Pi hardware. The mechanical drawings are usually made available for the benefit of those making accessories for the Pi (like cases), but not the full schematics. Production of Pi hardware is licensed to official production partners only, and you can't even buy the SoC.

Comment: This is useful!